# add a second antenna

Tags: antenna, bluetooth

My application requires to connect through Bluetooth reliably. I have an issue is that the receiver is not always in line of sight and when not, I experiment connection drop.

I would like to have 2 antennas in 2 different direction. The chipset is CSR 8635. Is that even possible to have dual antenna?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. That chip (like most) only uses a single antenna. If you added a 2nd antenna and somehow combined their signals (in the RF domain), you might improve performance in a specific direction, but you are also going to get nulls where the 2 antennas both pick up a signal and the phases are such that they cancel.

You'd really need a 2nd RF amplifier & demodulator. Alternatively just use 2 of those CSR 8635 ?

Comment: Thanks, that's a clear and concise answer. So, I am bound to find an optimal location for my unique antenna.